# Alpha transparency making wall transparent

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I have a simple textured wall, and it looked really clean so I downloaded a grungy texture from CG. Unfortunately, when I tried making the alpha channel invisible, I couldn't figure it out, so I just turned the alpha under the textures panel to 0 and enabled mask transparency which I turned down to 3.14 (cause pi is cool). Its not exactly the effect I want, because some of the white from the mask still discolors the wall, but the biggest problem is once I deselect it, it turns the entire wall transparent.

Here is what it looks like while selected: almost right

[image: wall textured while selected]

but once I deselect.

[image: wall textured while unselected]

What is the proper way to make the alpha channel disappear, while leaving the moldy-grunge intact and not making a gaping hole in my wall. This is a game prop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a grunge texture or decal is very easy (even easier then in cycles).

All you have to do is add a grunge or decal texture with a alpha channel under the base color,in your case the second texture slot.
Your material  and texture does not need any transparency. Both textures only influence the *Color*.
[image: texture slots]