# Part of object disappears when viewed through a transparent material

Tags: transparency

When using the Blender Game Engine, the parts of the model viewed through the windows becomes transparent and it's not a clipping problem. If I select a glass object the model viewed through the glass object shows up properly.

[image: transparency affects object view]

---

I have tried both solidify and double sided and it doesn't help. If I select a transparent object, the object then shows the model through the object. When I press play, then everything works right. In the image I have selected the 'glass door' on the left and the object can now been seen, but not through the other windows. I hope this is alright to answer like this, as I don't see away to include an image in  my comments.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31558/alpha-transparency-making-wall-transparent

I'm assuming you're using GLSL shading mode?

Comment: Yes I am using GLSL

Comment: What does it look like inside the game engine?

Comment: It look s fine when I press 'P' to activate the play mode

Answer (score 1):

My guess their normals are pointing to the opposite direction. One solution is to add a **solidify** modifier to it, or check in **double sided** in object data. The second option is maybe better for performance.

[image]