# How do I Make a Transparency to Decal my Object? (Blender Render Only)

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I can't find an answer to this question. I want to make a decal and add it on top of another texture I've already applied to my object (I can redo it if necessary).

I don't have the decals yet because I still have to make them, but I don't know how. I know that the background has to have something done to it to make it transparent, and I know that Blender has to handle the file as a transparency by adjusting the alpha channel, but that's all I know.

Can someone who has the time please step me through this and make it simple to learn? Maybe an example file that I can study?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of [Alpha transparency making wall transparent](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31558/2217), let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do really is save your texture in an image format that supports transparency. Any with alpha channels should do like PNG, TGA, TIFF, or any other supported by Blender.

You can use any image editing software like GIMP, or Krita, or Photoshop to remove the background of your image and make your decal texture.

Then in Blender add a new texture to your material

Under the *Properties Window > Texture Tab > Image Mapping* change the *Extension* mode to *Clipping*

Under the *Mapping* panel Change the *Coordinates* type to *Object* and bellow pick any object in your scene to control the position of your decal.

You may create an *Empty* type of object specifically for this, then use it to control the position of the decal, move it about, scale it to set the size, and rotate it to match the surface normal.

Have in mind that this will only work in the rendered view, viewport preview is not supported.[image: Object coordinates texture decal]

Example file
[image]

Comment: How about a sample file? Words help to a point, but a real example would be far better.

Comment: There you go, blend file added

Comment: The file is completely empty.

Comment: Weird, I'll check later today when I am back at the computer.

Comment: What do you mean file is empty? Just downloaded it and there's a demo icosphere with a decal texture applied with the technique described above. Try downloading it again, see if you somehow got a corrupt download

Comment: It's still the same. I get a bunch of empty windows that are set up so that getting out is difficult unless you know how to get the file menu up afgain. There's an Outliner showing an empty and a constraint, but they don't show up in the main window. The other windows are blank.

Comment: Open Blender without any file, then go to File > Open and untick the option"load UI" from the bottom left of the screen, then browse to and open the downloaded file. Anyway you don't need it, you should be able to do it easily from the above provided instructions

Comment: I don't need it like people don't need clear instructions.