# Small texture cannot be clipped in Material Viewport Shading, always repeats

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I want to set a texture on one side of a cube, but it shall only be very small. So I selected this one face in edit mode, “unwraped” it (i. e. created a UV map with just one face), and scaled it up in the UV/Image Editor.

When I now create a material and an associated texture, load my image, set Image Mapping → Extension to Clip and disable Mapping → From Dupli, there should only be one image, but it is always tiled over this face instead.

[image: Tiled texture on one face of cube]
[image: Data tab of texture]

Of course, furthermore, the whole cube should be green, as there is only one material. However, it works in Viewport Shading “Rendered”:

[image: Correctly cropped texture in viewport shading “Rendered”]

But this is not good enough for me, I need it in Viewport Shading “Material”, too. Is there a trick that helps me? Or is this viewport shading not able to clip (so missing feature or bug)?

I use Blender 2.79, Blender Render and Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know OpenGL viewport preview doesn't support texture clipping options, so they will always display tiling infinitely.

Also viewport material preview is quite limited, it is meant as a reference only.

They should render properly when pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> key regardless of render engine, though, except of course OpenGL renders.

Also see [How do I Make a Transparency to Decal my Object? (Blender Render Only)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56294/how-do-i-make-a-transparency-to-decal-my-object-blender-render-only)