# Unknown black and green objects added to Texture when UV Unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

[image: GIF of Green and black mirrored issues.]

Title kind of says it all, very confused since I'm quite new to Blender.

Have looked around but couldn't find anything to help, apologies if this is a nooby question.

There is this weird green and black thing; it looks kind of mirrored (the green part I mean.)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: @cegaton I have edited it now to include the GIF without link.

Comment: Are you using a texture with transparency? If yes, look up how to properly integrate the alpha channel into your material setup with [Blender Internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56297/30849) or [cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9268/30849). You should also include the renderer you are using as a tag (Internal, Cycles, Eevee).

Comment: @Leander The texture is using transparency; I need the background to be white (I thought just making the color of the part white would be enough) so I'll try making the background white instead of transparent. I'll tell you if this fixes my issue.