# How to put a transparent texture over a material in the blender render?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a model on which I want a patch of PNG texture but the rest of the model has no texture. What I want to achieve is:

Where the texture is not transparent - render the texture

Where the texture is transparent - render the material

Where no texture is defined - render the material

I can get the texture to show up in BlenderRender-view by turning on the material's 'face textures' option (having UV-mapped the faces that are to be textured) but this seems to turn off the material color (and I just get grey where there is no texture and black where the texture is transparent - presumably the texture is set to black under the transparency in the PNG).

Probably either something simple or I am taking entirely the wrong approach.

[image: model in blender with texture]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31558/2217 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18346/2217 say how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, David. Knowing that the thing I was trying to make was formally called a 'Decal' and I would have undoubtedly found it quickly myself. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy. After you set up your base material (in my case a blue color) go over to the Texture tab.

Add in the texture (it doesn't even need to have an alpha channel).
Now set the *Image Mapping* to *Clip*, if you don't the image will tile all over your object. (Do note that the clip option does not work with the *Texture* or *Material* shading in the 3D view, you have to be in rendered mode.)
Set the *Mapping* to *UV*, it is one of the easiest ways to do a decal type of texture.
Last, do **not** have this texture influence the alpha at all. The only thing this texture should *Influence* is the *Color*.
[image: texture settings]

That's it. Where the texture is, and is not transparent, the texture is displayed; everywhere else the material is displayed.

[image: rendered material]
This is what my material with the texture settings above looks like. The blender logo is a png with an alpha channel, the blue is from my diffuse color in the material.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something simple! Alpha is not Alpha! Of course! :-P All is working now, thanks greatly. :-D.

Answer (score 0):

A little more fiddling with the advice from @David above and these settings are working for me now:

[image]

I got the black square to go away by turning off the **Use Alpha** but the material still didn't come through :-( .

Turning on **Use Alpha** in the Image panel, then also **Alpha:Use** in the Image Sampling pane seemed to do it.

(I may have randomly clicked on other stuff, but I think I un-clicked everything that didn't turn out relevant, again!)